# DRF Specify required Header

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there a way to specify a required custom header for specific `View` classes?
On an API I am working, some information are passed using headers and I need to return BAD_REQUEST or similar if a header is missing.

I can think of ways of implementing it using mixins, but not sure if there is something in place that already does it.

Comment: It is possible to check. How do you think Token authentication(send via header) happens. Please reply for clarification and elaboration, will be happy to do so.

Comment: You can glean a lot from reading the Token authentication middleware code in DRF.

Comment: @Sayok88 thanks for your comment. My question is referring to whether there is built-in functionality to support this. I am aware there are ways to implement this ad-hoc. I will have a look at the middleware,

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by overriding **`dispatch()`** method of view as,

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from rest_framework import viewsets


class SampleViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer
    queryset = SampleModel.objects.all()

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if "HTTP_CUSTOM_HEADER" not in request.META:
            raise PermissionDenied('not found')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Example usage of custom-header using Python's request lib**

```
In [10]: wrong_header = {"custom-header-wrong":"soem value"}

In [11]: orginal_header = {"custom-header":"soem value"}

In [12]: requests.get(url=url,headers=wrong_header).status_code
Out[12]: 403

In [13]: requests.get(url=url,headers=orginal_header).status_code
Out[13]: 200
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking to do using a mixin, so I can drop it on every View that needs this check. I was just curious whether there is a built-in way of doing this that I could not find

Comment: I don't think so (I'm not aware of it)

Answer (score 0):

You could use permissions to set them up

```py
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class CustomHeaderPermission(BasePermission):
    REQUIRED_HEADERS = ("MyCustomHeader", "AnotherOne")

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        for header in self.REQUIRED_HEADERS:
            if header not in request.META:
                return False
        return True
```

and then add them up to your specific view or all the views from the settings file.